# create sticky headers in Android with titanium appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, sticky

I need to create a way to have sticky headers in my android app. I have tried the example in this link:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView

This example creates the desired effect but only on iOS.

I need something like this that is for android and developed in titanium:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSCAMJskUrA

Is there some model that I can import to use with my javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

please use this library for FloatingGroupExpandableListView

https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView/blob/master/README.md

Comment: this library is for android using java. I'm using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

For Android best one is [TellHRecyclerStickyHeaderView](https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerStickyHeaderView)Hope this will help you

Comment: This is for android studio. I'm using Titanium Appcelerator